# Failed to resolve: redstone.xmlrpc:xnlrpc:1.1.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am attempting to build an android app that uses the `wordpress-java` *Lib* to obtain the data from my site.

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.techedelicminds.techedelicminds"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'net.bican:jwordpress:0.7.0'
}
```

As you can see I have the correct compile code in my build.gradle yet the Error `"Failed to resolve: redstone.xmlrpc:xmlrpc:1.1.1"` continues to show up, and despite my best efforts I can not find anyone else on the internet that has run into this issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a dependency of jwordpress: https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/download_file?file_path=net%2Fbican%2Fjwordpress%2F0.7.0%2Fjwordpress-0.7.0.pom

Comment: Thank you, still my issues is that even including redstone.xmlrpc:xmlrpc:1.1.1 in my Dependencies leads to the same error. I'm a little over my head with Gradle but I've heard from many a person my best chance to learn to code is to attempt a project of my own. Is there some reason why even including the dependency would lead to the Failed to resolve error?